# Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension but some for reason this error keeps on happening. What I am trying to do is that I want to go to the last opened tab and execute a script in it. Could someone please help me?

Here is my background.js:

```
function executeScript(){
        chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
            var i=0;
            while (tabs[i]) {
                i++;
            };
            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {highlated: true});
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = i;
            chrome.scripting.executeScript(
            {
                target:{tabId: tabs[i].id},
                function: codeToExecute,
            });
        })
    }
    setTimeout(executeScript, 500);
```

And here is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Name of extension",
    "description": "Coded by furtuna with JS and ♥",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "script": "files/background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "scripting"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "files/main.html"
    }
}
```

[Image with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9uBU.png)

Comment: well you are accessing one index past that exists. You loop until you do not find any tabs. So i is going to be the index where the tab does not exist.

Comment: Nope. I checked and counted the tabs. The value of 'i' is how many tabs I have open.

Comment: Yes that is the count, but indexes start at ZERO, so again, you are accessing one greater than you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice that your while loop will stop when i there is no tab in index i. which is equal to the length of the tabs array.
don't forget that array indexes are starting from 0 so the last element would be the length of the array minus 1.

so when you try to get tabs[i] you will get undefined. and "undefined.id" throws an exception.

if your goal is to access the id of the last element i would advise you to to do as such:

```
tabs[tabs.length - 1].id
```